# Changing the verbatim font of Latex document to Inconsolata

Tags: fonts

I have long pieces of \LaTeX code given to me which look lie the following.

```
\begin{flushleft} \small
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\label{scrap1}\raggedright\small
\NWtarget{nuweb13}{} \verb@"../main.py"@\nobreak\ {\footnotesize {13}}$\equiv$
\vspace{-1ex}
\begin{list}{}{} \item
\mbox{}\verb@@\\
\mbox{}\verb@import sys@\\
\mbox{}\verb@sys.path.append('src/lib')@\\
\mbox{}\verb@@\\
\mbox{}\verb@import problem_foo\\
\mbox{}\verb@import problem_bar\\
\mbox{}\verb@   @\\
\mbox{}\verb@if __name__=="__main__":@\\
\mbox{}\verb@     if (len(sys.argv)==1):@\\
\mbox{}\verb@          print "Specify the problem"@\\
\mbox{}\verb@          sys.exit()@\\
\mbox{}\verb@@\\
\mbox{}\verb@     elif sys.argv[1] == "--problem-foo":@\\
\mbox{}\verb@          foo.run_handler()@\\
\mbox{}\verb@@\\
\mbox{}\verb@     elif sys.argv[1] == "--problem-bar":@\\
\mbox{}\verb@          bar.run_handler()@\\
\mbox{}\verb@@\\
\mbox{}\verb@@\\
\mbox{}\verb@     else:@\\
\mbox{}\verb@          print "Option not recognized"@\\
\mbox{}\verb@          sys.exit()@\\
\mbox{}\verb@@{\NWsep}
\end{list}
\vspace{-1.5ex}
\footnotesize
\begin{list}{}{\setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}\setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}}
```

I do not like the default font of the verbatim font of `\verb` that is being 
generated in my document. How do I tell \LaTeX to change the verbatim font
to [Inconslata](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/inconsolata/) ?

Note: I know, I can probbaly generate better looking output using listings environment for source code, but I am not allowed to edit the code-chunks 
I have been given. I just need a way to change the font of `\verb` to something nicer like inconsolata.